# How to change a blocks appearance on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that there is a command out there that changes the texture of a block, I just don’t know what it is.

Comment: It's `/setblock`, haha. But no, you can't change textures with commands. You should better ask about what you're actually trying to do, then we can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

there is no command to change a texture in-game. you'd need either a resource pack or to change texture files.